# How to manage multiple postgresql installs

Tags: linux, postgresql, ubuntu

I have Ubuntu Server 20.04 with postgresql 13 with postgis in use. I want to migrate to postgres 16 gradually, by having both versions side by side for a while and moving databases one by one. But first I need to "clean up" my installed packages I guess, and I am not sure about best way to do this and not broke my postgres 13 installation.

First, I've listed installed packages related to postgres:

```
me@myserver:/$ apt list --installed | grep postgre

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

postgresql-13-postgis-3-scripts/now 3.4.0+dfsg-1.pgdg20.04+1 all [installed,upgradable to: 3.4.1+dfsg-1.pgdg20.04+1]
postgresql-13-postgis-3/now 3.4.0+dfsg-1.pgdg20.04+1 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 3.4.1+dfsg-1.pgdg20.04+1]
postgresql-13/now 13.12-1.pgdg20.04+1 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 13.13-1.pgdg20.04+1]
postgresql-15-postgis-3-scripts/now 3.4.0+dfsg-1.pgdg20.04+1 all [installed,upgradable to: 3.4.1+dfsg-1.pgdg20.04+1]
postgresql-15-postgis-3/now 3.4.0+dfsg-1.pgdg20.04+1 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 3.4.1+dfsg-1.pgdg20.04+1]
postgresql-15/now 15.4-1.pgdg20.04+1 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 15.5-1.pgdg20.04+1]
postgresql-client-13/now 13.12-1.pgdg20.04+1 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 13.13-1.pgdg20.04+1]
postgresql-client-15/now 15.4-1.pgdg20.04+1 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 15.5-1.pgdg20.04+1]
postgresql-client-common/now 241.pgdg20.04+1 all [installed,upgradable to: 256.pgdg20.04+1]
postgresql-common/now 241.pgdg20.04+1 all [installed,upgradable to: 256.pgdg20.04+1]
postgresql-postgis-scripts/now 3.4.0+dfsg-1.pgdg20.04+1 all [installed,upgradable to: 3.4.1+dfsg-1.pgdg20.04+1]
postgresql-postgis/now 3.4.0+dfsg-1.pgdg20.04+1 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 3.4.1+dfsg-1.pgdg20.04+1]
```

and I was like "what the hell, I have postgres 15 installed?"

```
me@myserver:/$ pg_lsclusters
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory               Log file
13  main    5432 online postgres /dataraid/postgresql/13/main log/postgresql-%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S.log
15  main    5433 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/15/main  /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-15-main.log
```

Yep, I have, and it is even running, without me even knowing that. I guess it got installed sometimes when I did `apt upgrade`, because I have `postgresql-postgis` virtual package installed? Is that assumption correct?

Well, I dont want it, so let's uninstall it:

```
root@myserver:/# apt remove postgresql-15-postgis-3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libboost-serialization1.71.0 libfwupdplugin1 libgmpxx4ldbl libjson-perl libllvm10 libllvm9 libprotobuf-c1 libsfcgal1 libxmlb1 pgdg-keyring
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  postgresql-client-common
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  pgbouncer postgresql-13 postgresql-13-postgis-3 postgresql-15 postgresql-15-postgis-3 postgresql-common postgresql-postgis
The following packages will be upgraded:
  postgresql-client-common
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 7 to remove and 24 not upgraded.
Need to get 94.0 kB of archives.
After this operation, 127 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
```

Nope, that want to remove my postgres 13 also.

So, few questions:

1. how to safely uninstall postgres 15 in my case, leaving postgres 13 untouched?
2. how to ensure this does not happen again in the future?
3. how to install postgres 16 "the right way"? (I guess `apt install postgresql-16-postgis-3` speficically?)

Comment: 1) You are using the [PGDG repo ](https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/) which allows for multiple instances of Postgres to be installed side by side. 2) This is done by a PERL script `pg_wrapper` which you read up on with `man pg_wrapper` or `man  postgresql-common`. For more in depth I wrote two blogs [Install](https://aklaver.org/wordpress/2023/06/29/postgres-debian-ubuntu-packagingpart-1/) and [Usage](https://aklaver.org/wordpress/2023/07/01/postgres-debian-ubuntu-packagingpart-2/).

Comment: If you just want to drop the 15 cluster then do `pg_dropcluster --stop 15 main`. **NOTE** this is not reversible. To uninstall you might try `apt purge postgresql-15`.

Answer (score 0):

There are instances where installing some development packages or libraries for Postgres brings in extra versions.You can alternately find Postgres versions by `dpkg -l | grep postgresql`.  Then disable Postgres services, `sudo systemctl disable postgresql`. To ensure that Postgres-15 is completely removed, even its configuration file, do `sudo apt-get purge postgresql-15-postgis-3`. Remove the dependencies by `sudo apt autoremove`. You might be required to remove the data directory: `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/postgres`. Install Postgres-16 first `sudo apt-get -y install postgresql-16` and build postgis extension on top of it.